# Tycoon game on Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a tycoon game on Roblox, but a part of my code doesn't work... this problem occurs for every single tycoon within my game (as they all share almost the same lines of code)... when the player purchases the weapon panels using the in-game cash, they should be getting the weapon in their inventory when they come in contact with the panel...but the player doesn't seem to be getting the weapon. Here is the part of code related to the weapon panel :

```
wep = script.Parent.WeaponName.Value
deb = true
giv = script.Parent.Giver
function touch(part)
    local hum = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if hum then
        local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(part.Parent.Name)
        if plr then
            if deb == true then
                deb = false
                giv.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
                local weapon = game.Lighting:FindFirstChild(wep)
                local w2 = weapon:Clone()
                w2.Parent = plr.Backpack
                wait(script.Parent.RegenTime.Value)
                giv.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright violet")
                deb = true
            end
        end
    end
end
script.Parent.Giver.Touched:connect(touch)
```

Please help :(
I am not able to understand the problem in this giver script and as to why it doesn't give the player the particular weapon.

PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE  :  Lua

Comment: any own debugging attempts? add prints, make sure your logic is working as expected

Comment: It'd probably be more appropiate to ask this on a roblox-themed forum. Remember that the `part` can also be the child of a mesh which is in the player model, so also check if `part.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")` is true in your first `if` statement.

Comment: I couldn't say these are what is causing the script not to work, but for best practice, find the player using the Players service. For example,
`local Players = game:GetService("Players")`
`local character= part.Parent`
`local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)`. Also, storing things in lighting is highly discouraged, and replication should be managed through ReplicatedStorage or ReplicatedFirst. It's likely this is why it fails to work.